# c# get double from access database onto form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, numbers, double

I am trying to get data that is saved as Double in my access database. My application is suppose to pull data stored as double (Number -Data Type) and place it in a label for me to view. I can do it by just relabeling it as text, but it wont work with double.

Any suggestions would be helpful! Below is what i have, (1) is the column where my Double data is.

```
            str = "Select * from data where loc='" + loc + "'";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                label33.Text = dr.GetDouble(1);
```

Comment: what does "wont work" mean? Exception? Nothing? Wrong data?

Comment: Don't use `*` in sql-queries. That can cause nasty errors in future.

Comment: I dont get any errors/exceptions, just no data shows up on my label. @TimSchmelter, ill update to not use * . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is a typed language, you cannot assign a double to a string variable. This should work:

```
label33.Text = dr.GetDouble(1).ToString();
```

Side-note: Don't use `*` in sql-queries. That can cause nasty errors in future if the schmema changes. Instead name all of your columns.

You can also use `GetOrdinal` to get the index of the column, then you can use it's name what is less error-prone:

```
int dataColIndex = dr.GetOrdinal("DataCol");
double dataValue = dr.GetDouble(dataColIndex);
label33.Text = dataValue.ToString();
```

You should also consider to give your controls more meaningful names ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the detailed response. This worked perfectly...4 months into learning C#, learning never stops. Thank you!